# How to shuffle an array using a seed whereby the sequence of elements remains consistent when additional items are added to the array

Tags: arrays, random, shuffle, seed, deterministic

*Note: This question can apply to any programming language, for example Python or JavaScript.*

---

How would you shuffle an array of elements deterministically with a seed, but where the following is **also** guaranteed:

- If you add an additional element to the array before shuffling, the sequence of the original elements remains the same as with shuffling the original array.

I can probably explain this better with an **example**:

- Let's say the array [a, b, c] is shuffled with seed 123, and this results in the output [c, a, b].
- As you can see, **b comes after a, and a comes after c**.
- We add an additional element *to the end* of the array, [a, b, c, d], and proceed to shuffle with seed 123.
- This time, **b must still come after a, and a must still come after c**.
- The output might be [c, a, d, b] or [d, c, a, b], but *cannot* be [b, a, c, d].
- The same must apply if we continue to add more elements.

---

Edit: The positions of each element in the shuffled list should be completely random (certain positions should not be biased for a certain element), if mathematically possible.

Answer (score 1):

(I am pretty new to python)

You are adding the additional element at the end, But you can also insert it in a random position after the shuffle

```
import random
x = ['a','b','c']
random.Random(123).shuffle(x)
print(x)

x = ['a','b','c']
random.Random(123).shuffle(x)
x.insert(random.randint(0,len(x)),'d')
print(x)
```

But this will become problematic if more elements are added.

Comment: Thanks, interesting idea. Why would you say it's problematic with additional elements. Also I made a slight edit to the post for clarity, "The positions of each element in the shuffled list should be completely random (certain positions should not be biased for a certain element), if mathematically possible.". However, I think your approach does meet that requirement, so shouldn't change anything.